# implement ESC using Protractor to close popup window without any input elements

Tags: typescript, protractor, ui-automation, angular-e2e

is there someway to press ESC key, when there is no input element to perform the keypress on ?

the below solutions I found online does not work as I dont have an input element on the screen I am trying to ESC from.

```
element(by.id('No ID')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESC).perform();
```